# JPA Map Query Result to Class

Tags: java, jpa

I want to map a query result to a simple Pojo and can't figure out how to do it.

For example, I've got the following POJO:

```
public class TestMapper {
    private long tableAid;
    private String tableAValue;

    private long tableBid;
    private String tableBValue;
    ...
}
```

Now I want a simple query mapping into this class like:

```
List<TestMapper> testMappers = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "select * from tableA a, tableB b where a.id = b.id",
    TestMapper.class
).getResultList();
```

this query does not make very much sense but it represents what I want to do. I keep getting the Exception:

```
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class TestMapper]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TestMapper sql="select * from tableA a, tableB b where a.id = b.id")
```

what do I have to do, to solve this issue?

Comment: errm, match the selected column names up with the result class.

Comment: What version of JPA are you using? Only in 2.1 have they added the ability to map onto a non-entity class.

Comment: I'm using version 2.1